# xps 13 (2020), ubuntu 20.04 and Tier-1 OEM support

Tags: dell, 20.04, xps, oem

I've recently bought dell xps 13 (2020) developer edition. This machine was shipped to me with ubuntu 18.04 preinstalled.

I have seen that now this machine is [certified for ubuntu 20.04](https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop/models?query=&category=Laptop&level=&release=20.04%20LTS&vendors=Dell).
From what stated about [Tier-1 OEM support](https://ubuntu.com/blog/whats-new-in-ubuntu-desktop-20-04-lts): "*Starting with Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 LTS, it is now possible to obtain a certified device experience by installing the general release of Ubuntu. When installed on certified hardware, the device-specific enablement will be automatically installed and configured; just as it would be in the preloaded factory images.*"

I have therefore performed a clean installation of ubuntu 20.04 on my machine.

Unfortunately, the result seems not to be the one of a "preloaded factory image".
Dell repositories and pre-loaded application are not present in my fresh ubuntu 20.04 installation.

I did something wrong?
Someone else has this problem?

I would like to have ubuntu 20.04 on my dell machine, configured with dell repos, applications and dell configurations as the ones present in the shipped factory image.

Thank you in advance for any help.